# Could not find button to launch Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using

Tags: safari, automation, ios9, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium to launch Google.com on safari browser in iOS device(iPhone 6Plus).
This code is running fine when I am running it on simulator and able to open Google.com on safari browser but when same code runs on device , below error is getting encountered

**A new session could not be created. (Original error: Error. Could not find button to launch Safari. Make sure you are using the latest version of SafariLauncher that appium is using) (WARNING:
The server did not provide any stacktrace information).**

I am using below software--

- Appium: 1.4.13
- Mac: OSX Yosemite 10.10.5
- Eclispe: Mars(4.5.0)
- Xcode: 7.2
- Device: iPhone 6 Plus

Below is code

```
public class Josef {

WebDriver wd;  

 @BeforeTest  
 public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException { 
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "DEVICE_NAME");  
  capabilities.setCapability("udid", "DEVICE_UDID");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");  
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");  
  capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true); 
  capabilities.setCapability("app", "com.test.safarilauncher");
  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");  
  wd = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);//instantiate driver  
  wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
 }  

 @Test  
 public void testSearchPage() throws InterruptedException {  
  wd.get("https://www.google.co.in");  
  WebElement serachField = wd.findElement(By.name("q"));  
  serachField.sendKeys("youtube");  
  serachField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);  
  System.out.println(wd.getCurrentUrl());  
 }  

 @AfterTest  
 public void afterTest() {  
  //wd.close();  
 } }
```

I have also done below changes to device

- Enabled the Setting->Advanced->Web Inspector
- Enabled the Developer->UI Automation

And I also   Installed the ios_webkit_debug_proxy and
   Running command to ios_webkit_debug_proxy -d  Your Device's UDID:27753 to connect the device .

**EDIT1**

As suggested by Liam  But I am not able to run the command successfully. Below error I got while running the execution.

$ ./reset.sh --ios --real-safari
* Determining platform
* Platform is mac
---- Resetting / Initializing Appium ----
RESETTING NPM
* Installing new or updated NPM modules (including devDeps)
RESETTING GENERAL
* Nothing to do, not a git repo
RESETTING IOS

WARNING: you do not appear to have iOS7/8 SDK active

Setting iOS config to Appium's version
---- FAILURE: reset.sh exited with status 1 ----
---- Retry with --verbose to see errors ----

Comment: instead of using app capability try using "browserName" set to "Safari"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem. My method to get around it was to manually deploy SafariLauncher.

- `git clone https://github.com/budhash/SafariLauncher`.
- Then open it in xcode and code-sign it.
- Then deploy it to the device.
- Run `build.sh` in the SafariLauncher project.
- Then move SafariLauncher.zip into a appium/build/SafariLauncher, whereever that is on your machine.
- Then run `./reset.sh --ios --real-safari`.

Pretty sure this is not the intended method, but it is what I did and I can verify that it works.

Also, as econoMichael said, use the capability `"browserName", "safari"` instead of `"app", "safariLauncher"`.

Hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: Hi Liam . Thanks for help. But I am not able to run the command successfully. Error is added in Question description.

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of appium you are using

Comment: I'm using the github version - https://github.com/appium/appium. Master branch, latest edition.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the capability

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "safari");
```

and update the capability with app path

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", Your Safari launcher app path);
```

Comment: Can you add any explanation of why this change should be made?